# SQL Data Mining Concepts VS. Programming Concepts

Tags: sql, design-patterns

I am a beginner but know the basics and am peering into more advanced data mining and stored procedure routines. I have learned small concepts that mimic C# Design Patterns such as looping structures but have not seen much (on the web) about SQL Design Patterns.

I ask because I ran across this book [http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Design-Patterns-Programming-Focus/dp/0977671542](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977671542) but have also always been told that you will find better information on sites like Stack than in a book.

I've been told that for programming professionals Design Patterns are a must. Is this also the case for SQL programmers?

*(Wasn't sure if this belonged on Meta or not. It's not a question about the site but is a general  discussion question)

Comment: data mining is not "programming database queries". data mining is using statistical methods to derive patterns from data.

Comment: I understand. Some of the reports I've had to do have forced me to look at more advanced stored procs. Hence the question. But yes I probably should have worded that better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design patterns for SQL are very useful as well. Is it any good to gather data if you do not  store it properly and retrieve it back to make useful decisions?

I have found Joe Celco's books very useful on database design patterns. http://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celko/e/B000ARBFVQ

Comment: So you are a fan of getting a good book? I ask because I've run into many DBA's that say you should always write code and check sites if you run into a problem. They don't seem to think books help to much. Thank you also for your answer on Design Patterns. I guess the learning doesn't stop but thats a good thing!

Comment: I would suggest you read (books / blogs / etc) to better your knowledge and practice to better your skill.

Comment: My approach has been that if I want to gain an in depth understanding of a particular sub-area within SQL then books help a lot, but if I am trying to solve a problem in front of me right now than I turn to things like Google and Stackoverflow.  In short, someone who really wants to master SQL will probably use some of both.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you should read books. In the first place they tend to be written by people recognized for their expertise (not just anyone who happens to log into the site) so the information is likelier to start out as more accurate. Then they have editors who help make the presentation of the information better. Finally a good book should discuss in more depth than an SO post can do and thus you will get information at a deeper level than just the code to fix your current problem. This means your understanding will grow and you will know why you would do X vice Y and be able to expand that understanding to new problems.

DBAs who don't read books probably don't understand the internals of how the database works very well and are likely to be less effective than those who do read in depth about their profession.

A book I recommend is:

[http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=pd_sim_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)

Also books on performance tuning are critical to read if you want to use good patterns in your SQL. A huge number of performance problems are caused by badly designed SQL. YOu should know what works well and what doesn't. Those tend to be databse backend specific, so look for ones realting to the type of databases you support.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me early in my carrer. I would like to become a successful DBA and I would definately want an in-depth knowledge base like that of some of the users of Stack. Thanks Again!